# Pip-installed module does not import

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Here is my problem: To work, I need to to set up an environment by sourcing some script. This script is setting up a virtual environment that I was not aware of.

Until I needed to use `django` module that I did not have. So I used pip to install the module. It did not work, i got an error message `ImportError: No module named django` so I investigated why. I found out, that i am using a virtualenv.

Here is my `sys.path`:

```
['', 
'/home/user/myenv/release/lib/Linux_x86_64/debug', 
'/home/user/myenv/tools',
'/home/user/myenv/tools/virtualenv/lib/python27.zip', 
'/home/user/myenv/tools/virtualenv/lib/python2.7',
'/home/user/myenv/tools/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/home/user/myenv/tools/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/home/user/myenv/tools/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/home/user/myenv/tools/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/home/user/myenv/tools/python/lib/python2.7',
'/home/user/myenv/tools/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/home/user/myenv/tools/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/home/user/myenv/tools/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

If I try to install django again, I get a message from pip

```
$ pip install django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /home/usr/myenv/tools/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

My question is why and how do I fix this to use django?

**UPDATE**

I have tried running `source /home/user/myenv/tools/virtualenv/bin/activate`
and then install django with pip. No difference.

Comment: that is not how you django

Comment: Have you tried `activate`ing the virtual environment and installing Django **within** it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe how? If you mean sourcing the script that sets the environment up and then running 'pip install django', then yes, I did it.

Comment: @nananananaBATMAN Are you invoking the virtualenv python interpreter when launching your django project?